# _fullpath Giving Hex Value in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, directory, getcwd

I'm trying to find out what my crrent working directory is. I've tried using both `_fullpath` and `_getcwd` as part of `<direct.h>`. However, all it gives me is an 8-byte hex value (such as `5504CA90`).

Why is it giving me this, and how can I get the correct cwd? I am using Visual Studio 2015 in C++.

My code looks like this:

```
std::cout << "CWD: " << _fullpath << "\n";
```

And it gives me this output:

```
CWD: 0F8CCA90
```

However, it gives me a different hex value every time I run it.

Comment: Please provide your code. Without it your question is meaningless.

Comment: Hex value??? Everything is hex :) Try to interpret it as `char *`.

Comment: Interpreting it as a (char *) produces random characters, such as "ï Uï∞j".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling `_fullpath`/`getcwd` method. Your code will simply print its address. This is the hex value, you are getting in the console output. To *call* method you have to supply its *parameters*:

> char *_getcwd(     char *buffer,    int maxlen  );

```
char szPath[255];
char* pszPath = _getcwd(szPath, sizeof(szPath)/sizeof(char));
if(pszPath)
  std::cout << pszPath << std::endl;
```